# error C2893: Failed to specialize function template with CTPL

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use CTPL for thread pooling.  As a test, I'm trying to get it to use a thread function inside a class.  With the code that follows, I'm getting this error:

```
error C2672: 'ctpl::thread_pool::push': no matching overloaded function found
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::future<unknown-type> ctpl::thread_pool::push(F &&)'
note: With the following template arguments:
note: 'F=void (__thiscall TestClass::* )(int)'
```

Here's the code:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    void testWorker(int id)
    {
        // do something
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ctpl::thread_pool p(2);    
    p.push(&TestClass::testWorker);
    p.stop(true);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the part of CTPL that is being referenced:

```
template<typename F>
auto push(F && f) ->std::future<decltype(f(0))> {
    auto pck = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(0))(int)>>(std::forward<F>(f));
    auto _f = new std::function<void(int id)>([pck](int id) {
        (*pck)(id);
    });
    this->q.push(_f);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
    this->cv.notify_one();
    return pck->get_future();
}
```

I suck at templates and I'm pretty sure that's what's killing me.  Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: I suggest removing the `threadpool` tag.  Your problem is nothing to do with thread-pooling algorithms or libraries.  (I don't think it's to do with templates either - but that's not at all obvious.)

Comment: Fair enough - removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing to do with templates (apart from the lousy error message).  `&TestClass::testWorker` is a pointer-to-member-function.  If you have:

```
const auto tw = &TestClass::testWorker
```

You can only call the function like:

```
TestClass tc;
tc.*tw(0);
// or
TestClass* ptc = &tc;
ptc->tw(0);
```

If you want to be able to call the function without an instance of a class to call it on, then you need to make `testWorker` static:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    static void testWorker(int id)
    {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Comment: Ugh.  I missed the static.  Thanks Martin!

Comment: Easily done.  Now what you need is a compile time assert that will fail with a clear error message when one of your colleagues does the same thing in six months time.  How to write that would be an interesting question ....